# how to get user from sql who fulfill following these criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get users from mysql database if they have created a note with `weather type = 'cloud','rain','clear'` and not those who have missed even one out of these three.

eg.

```
id  user_id weather_type
1   12      cloud
2   12      rain
3   12      clear
4   14      rain
5   15      clear
```

now here only user 12 have created notes with all three `weather_type` so only 12 should be fetched not 14 and 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select   user_id 
from     mytable 
where    weather_type in ('cloud','rain','clear')
group by user_id
having   count(distinct weather_type) = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM tab
WHERE weather_type IN ('cloud','rain', 'clear')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(weather_type='cloud') > 0
   AND SUM(weather_type='rain')  > 0
   AND SUM(weather_type='clear') > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27495/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╗
║ user_id ║
╠═════════╣
║      12 ║
╚═════════╝
```

If you need all fields you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE user_id IN (prev_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id from table_name where weather_type in ('cloud','rain','clear')
group by user_id
having count(distinct weather_type) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT user_id FROM tablex WHERE weather_type in ('cloud','rain','clear') 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT weather_type) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat function as below :

```
select user_id,weathers from 
  (select user_id, group_concat(weather_type) 
      weathers from tbl1 group by user_id
  )t1
  where find_in_set('cloud',weathers)>0 and 
   find_in_set('rain',weathers)>0 and
   find_in_set('clear',weathers)>0 ;
```

I tested it and it works correctly.

More info :

A better and general solution for this kind of problem is :
Define another table named e.g. 'must_be' with two columns 'must_id' and 'weather' and fill it by favorite values like below:

```
must_id       weather
  1             cloud
  2             rain
  3             clear
```

Then use below query to fetch desired rows without hard code any value:

```
select user_id,count(*) cnt from
  (select distinct user_id,weather_type from tbl1 join must_be on(weather_type=weather) ) t1 
  group by user_id having cnt=(select count(*) from must_be);
```

In the above query distinct keyword is necessary to get correct result in special situations.

After reading "trincot" response I decided to make my query better:

```
select user_id from tbl1 join must_be on(weather_type=weather)
  group by user_id 
  having count(distinct weather_type)=(select count(*) from must_be);
```